# Is there a way to make this kind of loop shorter and nicer?

Tags: wp-query, templates

Here is my loop code, i want to call **different page templates** for **different pages**. Please notice that this is a **one-page-layout**.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );?>  <!-- get only pages -->

<?php query_posts($args); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  <!-- loop with pages starts -->

<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>  <!-- get post/pageID --> 

<?php   if ($id == 5) : include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page_special.php' );

        else: include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page_all.php' );

        endif; 
?>
```

Would it be possible to change the `if ($id == 5)` with `is_page` or sth like that?

Comment: Why do you wrap every single line with php-tags? It's enough to open the php-mode at the beginning and do we it at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a few improvements.

- Needlessly opening and closing PHP tags is a timewaster, makes it harder to read, and means more typing
- PHP Alt/short style syntax isn't going to play as nicely with the editor. Use {} instead, and your IDE may even help you type out the closing brace automagically.
- Query_posts, never, ever use it. There is no valid use case that isn't covered by WP_Query or the pre_get_posts filter
- Dont put a trailing ?> at the end of a PHP file
- Use PHP comments not HTML comments
- get_template_part should be used instead of include
- You made no attempt to do cleanup after your query
- You never checked to see if any pages were found at all
- You're using page in your template names, this could cause clashes with the template heirarchy and may not load the template you think in some circumstances

So lets begin:

```
<?php

// grab pages
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// did we actually find posts?
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // while there are still posts
    while ( $query->have_posts()) {
        // setup the current post data/globals
        $query->the_post();

        // grab its ID
        $id = get_the_ID();
        if ($id == 5) {
            get_template_part( 'page_special' );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'page_all' );
        }
    }
    // cleanup after ourselves
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no pages were found!
}
```

Now, you can use get_template_part to further extend this.

First, I would swap this out to use 'content' rather than 'page' as the main identifier. So:

- page_all.php becomes content.php
- page_special.php becomes content-special.php

Note the use of - not _.

Then, I would modify the code that loads the content template, like so:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_the_ID() );
```

If you land on page 4 for example, it will attempt to load content-4.php, and if that doesn't exist, it will load content.php. You can pass in anything you want as the second parameter, and it'll also look in child/parent themes. Tie this to a custom field/post meta and you can extend it further

Comment: Hi Tom!
Thank you very much for your detailed and commented solution. I like the `get_template_part( 'content', get_the_ID() );` part because i think this is what i was lookin for.
You might have noticed that i'm a PHP noob but you gave me very good starting advices. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped, if you're happy with it you could mark it as accepted? I'd say the most important note to stress is query_posts, it's used in so many tutorials yet it's can cause all manner of issues, and it essentially doubles the amount of work WordPress has to do

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `query_posts`. Check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts?rq=1) for more info.

Secondly, post ID is probably not a good thing to differentiate on: duplicating database tables can easily become a pain in case of multiple-server development flows (i.e. one for dev, optionally another for QA, and one for live).

I found it the least brittle to tie logic to a custom field or something similar, such as a plugin setting which allows the user to specify the page ID(s) to show a different template for.

Comment: hey dalbaeb! thank you for the link. I hope i will get into the "query thing" soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I love [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
$part = ( 5 === (int) get_the_ID() ) ?
  'page_special' : 'page_all';
get_template_part( $part );
```